# cmake error target OpenGL::GL not found, when building with conda (ok with pip)

Tags: opengl, cmake, pip, anaconda, setuptools

I am trying to build a conda package for python library based on a C++ code :
https://gitlab.com/cytosim/cytosim/-/tree/pybind

I made a CMakeLists.txt and asetup.py file which allows me to install libraries via pip :
https://gitlab.com/cytosim/cytosim/-/blob/pybind/pycytoplay/CMakeLists.txt
https://gitlab.com/cytosim/cytosim/-/blob/pybind/setup.py

And so `pip install cytosim` works beautifully provided the adequate libraries are installed on the system.

However, if *in the same environment* I use `conda build . -c conda-forge` (with an [adequate meta.yaml file](https://gitlab.com/cytosim/cytosim/-/blob/pybind/meta.yaml), I get an error :

> CMake Error at CMakeLists.txt:523 (target_link_libraries):
> Target "cytoplay" links to:
>
> ```
>  OpenGL::GL
> ```
>
> but the target was not found.  Possible reasons include:
>
> ```
>  * There is a typo in the target name.
>  * A find_package call is missing for an IMPORTED target.
>  * An ALIAS target is missing.
> ```

I get this error only for `conda build`, not for `pip install`, nor `cmake .` ;  it happens both in a very crowded system and conda environment, and a brand new conda environement on a clean virtual machine, both Ubuntu 22.04.

Also note that there is a `find_package(OpenGL)` in the makefile, that does not yield any problem. I am also requiring cmake>3.14, so openGL things should be good.

I tried to add some opengl libs to the build requirements in meta.yaml (eg. pyopengl and mesalib), to no avail (and even if it worked, it would not explain the discrepancy between plain pip and conda build).

What could cause this ? Any fix ?

Comment: I'm struggling a bit, but it seems that installing with conda, and with pip (in the same conda envionement) is not the same thing - either cmake is different, or cmake has access to different libraries.